# convert int to ascii - more than one character in rune literal

Tags: go

How do I convert into to its ASCII?

In java it's `System.out.println((char)(49)); //gives 1`

I tried

```
a := '42'
fmt.Println(rune(a))
```

I get `more than one character in rune literal`

Comment: Pass the int directly to the rune function.

Comment: @ShubhamVasaikar i get the same number you mean `rune(42); //gives 42`?

Comment: This ?: https://play.golang.org/p/LaX_vTqqPez

Comment: You're trying to declare a as a `rune`, not an `int`, but compilation fails because you're using more than one character in the rune literal (two characters, `4` and `2`, between the single quotes). Did you mean `a := 42` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is in this variable:

```golang
a := '42'
```

A byte literal may only contain one character, use this instead;

```golang
a := byte(42)
```

Edit:
Use  `string(a)` to get the expected results, like boo said.

Comment: i think you also have to add a `string(a)` in your answer to get what I actually asked

Answer (score 6):

Use a [string conversion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions_to_and_from_a_string_type) to convert an ASCII numeric value to a string containing the ASCII character:

```
fmt.Println(string(49)) // prints 1
```

The `go vet` command warns about the `int` to `string` conversion in the this code snippet because the conversion is commonly thought to create a decimal representation of the number. To squelch the warning, use a `rune` instead of an `int`:

```
fmt.Println(string(rune(49))) // prints 1
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/eyDZNATLGPS).

This works for any rune value, not just the ASCII subset of runes.

Another option is to create a slice of bytes with the ASCII value and convert the slice to a string.

```
b := []byte{49}
fmt.Println(string(b))  // prints 1
```

[Run it on the playground](https://play.golang.org/p/LyCS9S6Kk5b)

A variation on the previous snippet that works on all runes is:

```
b := []rune{49}
fmt.Println(string(b))  // prints 1
```

Comment: `go vet` [warns](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/32479) against int-to-string conversion. There is even [a well-received proposal to disallow such conversions altogether](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/3939); therefore, I wouldn't encourage it.

Comment: @JonNickles no, I actually did the `string(a)` from the accepted answer myself to get what i want. thanks for your answer

Answer (score 3):

```
fmt.Printf("%c", 49)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose to do like this, in a very simple term explaining.

```
i := 1
fmt.Println("number value", i)

s := strconv.Itoa(i)
fmt.Println("string value", s)

a := []rune(s)[0]
fmt.Println("ascii value", a)

n := string(a)
fmt.Println("back to string value", n)
```

and output is following:

```
number value 1
string value 1
ascii value 49
back to string value 1
```

I know this is not the best one answer, but still it works fine without any issue.